# Can't assign a JSON result to UILabel (error "UILabel.text must be used from main thread only"

Tags: json, swift5

How can i assign a JSON result to a UILabel. Although my code run's and the result is perfectly printed on the console, i can't assign the result to a label. If i put the following line self.weatherLabel.text = metarFeed.sanitized to assign the result i get an error "UILabel.text must be used from main thread only"
I think it has got to do with the result not ready when i want to write the label but can't get my head around it to fix it.

I tested this also in a separate function but that gives the same error.

(I use normally a stackview to present result in a row, so that's the code underneath the ViewDidLoad stuff)

Thanks!

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var stackViewWeatherRow         = UIStackView()
    var weatherLabel                = UILabel()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        configureStackViewWeatherRow ()
        
       let urlString = "URL where the weather report is requested "
       let url = URL(string: urlString)
       
        guard url != nil else {
            return
        }
        
        let session = URLSession.shared
        
        let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
            if error == nil && data != nil {
                
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                
                do {
                    let metarFeed = try decoder.decode(MetarFeet.self, from: data!)
                    self.weatherLabel.text = metarFeed.sanitized
                    print (metarFeed.sanitized)
                }
                catch {
                    print ("Error in JSON parsing")
                }
                
            }
        }
        dataTask.resume()
    }


    func configureStackViewWeatherRow () {
        view.addSubview(stackViewWeatherRow)
        stackViewWeatherRow.axis = .horizontal
        stackViewWeatherRow.distribution = .equalCentering
        stackViewWeatherRow.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        setStackViewWeatherConstraints()
        configureWeatherLabel()
        
    }

    func setStackViewWeatherConstraints () {
        stackViewWeatherRow.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
        stackViewWeatherRow.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 50).isActive = true
        stackViewWeatherRow.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
        stackViewWeatherRow.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    }
    
    func configureWeatherLabel() {
        view.addSubview(weatherLabel)
        weatherLabel.text = "Weather Report"
        weatherLabel.textColor = .systemBlue
        weatherLabel.font = UIFont(name:"AvenirNext-DemiBoldItalic", size: 15.0)
        weatherLabel.textAlignment = .left
        weatherLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        weatherLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        weatherLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        stackViewWeatherRow.addArrangedSubview(weatherLabel)
    }
    
}
```

MetarFeed.swift Swift file:

```
import Foundation

struct MetarFeet: Codable {
    var sanitized:String = ""
    // sanitized is a line of text with the weather report like
   // CYVR 191500Z 10004KT 15SM FEW016 FEW110 BKN120 BKN240 02/01 A3047 RMK SC1AC2AC4CS1 SC TR SLP319
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that handler which accepts data, response and error is called on background thread. What you need to do is dispatch the call of setting the text to main thread:

```
let metarFeed = // ...
DispatchQueue.main.async { 
    self.weatherLabel.text = metarFeed.sanitized
}
// rest of the code
```